# Pass a4j:actionparam's name attribute to the backing bean

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I am trying to get the **a4j:actionparam** name's attribute value (e.g. here it is minimum), but it isn't work:

```
<h:inputText value="#{limit.minimum}"
                             styleClass="font11 inputText1"
                             size="5" >
                   <a4j:support event="onclick" actionListener="#{accountManagementBeanJSF.setLimitDefaultValues}" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="withdrawLimitsTable">
                   <a4j:actionparam value="#{limit.ps}"
                                    assignTo="#{accountManagementBeanJSF.newLimitPS}"
                                    name="minimum"/>
                   </a4j:support>
                </h:inputText>




 public void setLimitDefaultValues(ActionEvent event) {
    if (customerProfile != null) {
        String attributeName2 = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("minimum");
        LOGGER.info("Attribute minimum   " + attributeName2);
        //LOGGER.info("maximum   " + maxAttributeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the `a4j:actionparam value` becomes an attribute of `h:inputText`? Why don't you ask `accountManagementBeanJSF.newLimitPS` for the actual value as it should be assigned there? Can you provide details regarding "it isn't work"?

Comment: in logs I get null values

Comment: So, I need to know how I can pass a4j:actionparam's name attribute to the backing bean